# Determining distances MySQL

Tags: mysql

My code is as follows and should work but for some reason it is not recognizing wm_stores.lat in the join statement.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
SELECT wm_dcs.dc_id, wm_stores.store_id
FROM wm_dcs
JOIN wm_stores
    ON wm_stores.lat BETWEEN wm_dcs.lat - (250.0 / 69.0)
        AND wm_dcs.lat + (250.0 / 69.0)
        AND wm_stores.lon BETWEEN wm_dcs.lon - (250.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(wm_dcs.lat))))
        AND wm_dcs.lon + (250.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(wm_dcs.lat))))
        AND  (69.0 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(wm_dcs.lat) * COS(RADIANS(stores.latitude))
            * COS(RADIANS(dc.longitude - stores.longitude))
            + SIN(RADIANS(dc.latitude))
            * SIN(RADIANS(wm_stores.lon)))))) <= 250.0;
```

Different Version of code:

```
set @dc_lat = 40.811973 ;
set @dc_lon = -73.946299 ;

select wm_stores.store_id,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(@dc_lat) ) * cos( radians(wm_stores.lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( wm_stores.lon ) - radians(@dc_lon) ) + sin( radians(@dc_lat) ) 
* sin( radians( wm_stores.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
from wm_stores
having distance <= 250
order by distance asc;
```

Comment: Please always include exact error messages and table definitions

Comment: Also, can you give the table table schema please? For all we know, `wm_stores.lat` doesn't actually exist

Comment: Error message - Unknown column 'stores.latitude' in 'on clause'

Comment: lat and lon are columns in the wm_dcs and wm_stores tables

Comment: please ***edit*** your question and output `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`

Comment: have you tried to set conditions in where clause instead of join clause?

Answer (score 0):

In your query

```
SELECT wm_dcs.dc_id, wm_stores.store_id
FROM wm_dcs
JOIN wm_stores
    ON wm_stores.lat BETWEEN wm_dcs.lat - (250.0 / 69.0)
        AND wm_dcs.lat + (250.0 / 69.0)
        AND wm_stores.lon BETWEEN wm_dcs.lon - (250.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(wm_dcs.lat))))
        AND wm_dcs.lon + (250.0 / (69.0 * COS(RADIANS(wm_dcs.lat))))
        AND  (69.0 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(wm_dcs.lat) * COS(RADIANS(stores.latitude))
            * COS(RADIANS(dc.longitude - stores.longitude))
            + SIN(RADIANS(dc.latitude))
            * SIN(RADIANS(wm_stores.lon)))))) <= 250.0;
```

I noticed there is no table like `stores` but you have used `stores.latitude` and `stores.longitude` in your query. May be this is causing the error message  `Unknown column 'stores.latitude' in 'on clause'`.

I suggest you to re-examine the code

```
AND  (69.0 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(wm_dcs.lat) * COS(RADIANS(stores.latitude))
            * COS(RADIANS(dc.longitude - stores.longitude))
            + SIN(RADIANS(dc.latitude))
            * SIN(RADIANS(wm_stores.lon)))))) <= 250.0;
```

Comment: Thank you!  It was totally my mistake, I was not referencing the correct tables.  Also, would you know how i could display the distances at the end of the query?

Comment: @ElDiablo I suggest you to post it as another question.Please refer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query as to how to ask a good question so that your post will get all the attentions :)

Comment: Hey, it is what it is, I'm new to all this and just trying to get some answers.

Comment: In your question I see only the query you tried, just by looking the query I am unable to know what you exactly needed.For that you need to specify what your intentions are, what you tried so far, show us your table structure with some sample data for us to try and help you.